# converting a named graph into a graph object

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data

I am seeking the edge lists of the complements of named graphs on n vertices. At first sight I would use

```
G=Part[GraphData[n],i]
GC=GraphComplement[G]
edges=EdgeList[GC]
```

However GraphComplement requires a graph object. How do I convert G into an object accepted by GraphComplement? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you try `GraphComplement[GraphData[GraphData[n][[i]]]]`?

Answer (score 2):

`GraphData[5]` returns a list of specifications of graphs with 5 vertices.  Apply `GraphData` again to such a specification to get an actual graph.

For example,

```
GraphData[{"Wheel", 5}]
```

where `{"Wheel", 5}` is the last element from `GraphData[5]`.

The [`GraphData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html) documentation page has many such examples.